# LaTeX manuscript conversion failed

Tags: equations, errors, compiling

I was trying to submit a manuscript compiled in latex to a journal, and to upload the latex source files. I got some error messages. There were  problems compiling your ZIP into a PDF and I should upload a corrected file.

Could someone please advise on how best to write this equation within the text of the manuscript?

```
\begin{equation*}
    \[        \mathrm{NTR} = \left\frac{(Eligibility=1\;~'MSM' )~and~(Take-Up=0 \;~'Survey' )}{All~Eligible~HHs~(Eligibilty=1~'MSM' )}
\end{equation*}
```

Also, how to write this correctly within the text  `($\pi=0$ )`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can not have `\[`  or `\]`  in `equation`, remove them.   `Eligibility` should be `\mathrm{Eligibility}`

Comment: and \left is missing a delimiter.

Comment: it might help if you showed how you wanted this to look, havingan equation such as Eligibility=1 in the numerator of a fraction is rather strange

Comment: Thank you all, it is meant to show how the rate is calculated thus the numerator is more of a condition. If eligibility =1 and if reported take-up equals zero. My equation now looks like this: \begin{equation*}
            \mathrm{NTR} = {\frac{(\mathrm{Eligibility}=1\;~'MSM' )~and~(\mathrm{Take-Up}=0 \;~'Survey' )}{\mathrm{All~Eligible~HHs~}(\mathrm{Eligibility}=1~'MSM' )}}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Is there an idea or program on how to fix code errors for beginners? I wanted to submit it to a journal, I got the pdf compiled in my Overleaf already, but not in the journal's system.